# expo-document-picker doesn't work on ios after all the actions mentioned in guide

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to set up `expo-document-picker` for our expo app. On android it works fine but it fails on ios.

Accordingly to [official guide](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/) I did the following:

1. Set `sesIcloudStorage` to `true` in app.json
2. Enabled iCloud with CloudKit support and set up iCloud container
3. Removed existing provisioning profile
4. Added `expo-document-picker` plugin with `appleTeamId` to app.json (though the guide doesn't say to do it)
5. Ran build and let Expo generate new provisioning profile

And after all of that I still keep getting this error:

> Error: DocumentPicker requires the iCloud entitlement. If you are using ExpoKit, you need to add this capability to your App Id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `expo-document-picker@10.3.0` have troubles with types starting with `application/`. So setting type to `*/*` as a workaround fixed the issue.